# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ẁ (U+1E81)

Tags: symbols, characters

I'm trying to use the 'ẁ' character in my text, however it doesn't show on the right hand side of latex and throws the following error:

Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ẁ (U+1E81)

I tried adding \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} to the top of my document, which then gave another error telling me to add 'utf8, latin1' to my \documentclass which I tried but this is also not working.

Is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: Apparently this unicode character isn't available yet

Comment: Which TeX engine do you use: pdfTeX, XeTeX, or LuaTeX?

Comment: .note. Inputenx supports this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ẁ` character is not supported in Latin-1; save your file as UTF-8 and add

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and also

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E81}{\`w}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E81}{\`w}

\begin{document}

Is the character ẁ used in some language?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A great place for finding the char number is https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile your documents. They support utf8 input encoding natively (in fact, it's the only input encoding they support...). Do also make sure you use a font that features the character `ẁ`.

[image]

```
% Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and load a font that contains "ẁ"
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} ẁ
\setmainfont{Cardo} ẁ
\setmainfont{Junicode} ẁ
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (non exclusive) list of fonts on CTAN that have this character (it belongs to the series *Latin extended additional* in the unicode description):

Latin Modern –erewhon –Linux Libertine O – ebgaramond – tex-gyre.

Comment: It might be useful if you provided an MWE. :-)

Comment: @Mico: I'll provide one in a moment…