# Macro to auto-convert english quotes ("") to french («»)

Tags: macros, extended-characters

French quotes can easily be obtained using \og and \fg commands. Although this is perfectly fine, it's not very intuitive to use them when typing.

Is there a way to make latex automatically converting odd " quotes to \og and even " quotes to \fg, using some \renewcommand magic or something in the like ?

Comment: Why not using directly « and » unicode chars?

Comment: @Rmano They are not available on my keyboard, so opening the unicode text char and copying them is even more than using \og and \fg in my opinion.

Comment: Isn't this automatically achieved with `csquotes` package?

Comment: I use extensively the [compose key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key) for this kind of tasks, together with this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304643/38080 — I strongly advise it (« for me is `compose`,`<`,`<`  — really fast, especially if you define CapsLock, the Most Absurd Key(™), as a Compose...)

Comment: `\usepackage{newunicodechar} \newunicodechar{“}{«} \newunicodechar{”}{»}`

Comment: May I suggest to install the « Galéron keyboard driver », available [here](http://accentuez.mon.nom.free.fr/Clavier-Galeron.php)? It gives an easy access to « French », “American” and ‘British quotes’, accented capital letters, &c.

Comment: @Bernard Je viens de suisse, donc je n'ai pas un clavier AZERTY, et ce ne serait en aucun cas possible pour moi de m'adapter à un clavier différent du QWERTZ.

Comment: @Bregalad: J'aurais pensé qu'en Suisse romande, on utilisait un clavier azerty (ou une variante, comme nos amis belges)… Et le Bépo ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following definition:

```
\catcode`\"=13
\def"{\begingroup\og \def"{\fg\endgroup}}

Aha "test" more "once".
```