# How can I use unicode symbols in TeX source?

Tags: unicode

I've tried using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, but that throws an error:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char µ (U+B5)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Whatever I do, unicode character in the source either do not appear, or do not appear *and* throw an error.  I would like to use both Russian and mathematical symbols in my source code.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think the least troublesome solution would be using a unicode egine like XeTeX or LuaTeX with an appropriate font.

Comment: are you planning onto using µ in math mode too?

Comment: @jfbu: Yes.  I find it easier to read the source when it looks somewhat like the output.

Comment: General question: [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex)

Answer (score 6):

Probably this will miss more complex scenarios, but [from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304643/38080):

```
%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B5}{\ifmmode\mu\else\textmu\fi}
%
% use http://shapecatcher.com/ to find the char
% or https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html

\begin{document}

This is a textmode µ and this a math mode one: $µ_µ$.

\end{document}
```

[image: Output from above]

If you do not want to define everything, you need to switch to a native unicode TeX engine, like for example `xelatex`. If you compilte with `xelatex` the following code:

```
%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%
% use http://shapecatcher.com/ to find the char
% or https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html

\begin{document}

Is the character ẁ used in some language?

This is a textmode µ and this a math mode one: $_$. 
(But be careful, math mu is a different unicode codepoint,
\texttt{1D707}.)

\end{document}
```

to obtain:

[image]

Where I am using [the `unicode-math` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118244/what-is-the-difference-between-unicode-math-and-mathspec); I found the mathmode µ codepoint at [shapcatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/block/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols).

Comment: Isn't that textmode µ really ugly?

Comment: Is there any way to do this but without having to declare every symbol you want to use?

Comment: ...I edited the answer.

Comment: Node that `unicode-math` package also makes the output characters Unicode, see [xetex - What is the difference between unicode-math and mathspec? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118244/what-is-the-difference-between-unicode-math-and-mathspec?noredirect=1&lq=1)